# Oracle date is converted to datetime in python

Tags: python, oracle, datetime

When i use `trunc` function in oracle and run the query in `oracle developer` i get only date value from the datetime field. for eg below query

```
Select trunc(min(Transaction_Date)) as StartDate,
                trunc(Max(Transaction_Date)) as EndDate
                from table1
```

returns

```
29-feb-2016 02-oct-2016
```

But the same query when used in python and printed to output file

```
print("start",row[0])
print("end",row[1])
dateperiod=str(row[0]).strip() + " - " + str(row[1]).strip()
print("date period :", dateperiod)
```

Output

```
('start', datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 29, 0, 0))
('end', datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 2, 0, 0))
('date period :', '2016-02-29 00:00:00 - 2016-10-02 00:00:00')
```

The output i need is `2016-02-29 - 2016-10-02` . Wonder why it changes format in python. Please help with the right solution

Tried using `to_date(min(Transaction_Date),'YYYY-MM-DD')` but strangely no change in the output.

Comment: The DATE type in Oracle is a timestamp, having fields YEAR, MONTH, DAY, HOUR, MINUTE, and SECOND. It's only accurate down to the second, having no capability for sub-second resolution, which is why there's also a TIMESTAMP type.

Comment: i think to_char is what i am after. replace to_date with to_char so that it is not a date datatype anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Just format the date in the format you want:

```
dateperiod = "{0:%Y-%m-%d} - {1:%Y-%m-%d}".format(row[0], row[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the other answer also makes sense when it is to format the date value from oracle in code. But for me a char type would suffice . So used as below and it all works the same

```
to_char(min(Transaction_Date),'DD-MM-YY') as MinDate,
```

Comment: Don't use the 'DD-MM-YY' mask; always use 'YYYY' for year. Don't even ask why - just use 'YYYY'.